# Unwanted Upgrade ElasticSearch version

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kibana, upgrade

I made a mistake by trying to upgrade my elasticsearch version from 6.3.2 to 7.2.0.

I launched my container with the new version but I realized that kibana does not work anymore.

So I decided to downgrade elasticsearch to 6.3.2 to get a quick fix but it still not working. I got the following error :

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future release.
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: UseAVX=2 is not supported on this CPU, setting it to UseAVX=1
[2019-07-23T14:21:59,939][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2019-07-23T14:22:00,105][WARN ][o.e.b.ElasticsearchUncaughtExceptionHandler] [] uncaught exception in thread [main]
org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: ElasticsearchException[java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:205, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-205.st]]; nested: IOException[failed to read [id:205, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-205.st]]; nested: IllegalArgumentException[[node_meta_data] unknown field [node_version], parser not found];
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:140) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.execute(Elasticsearch.java:127) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.EnvironmentAwareCommand.execute(EnvironmentAwareCommand.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.mainWithoutErrorHandling(Command.java:124) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.cli.Command.main(Command.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-cli-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:93) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.main(Elasticsearch.java:86) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchException: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:205, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-205.st]
        at org.elasticsearch.ExceptionsHelper.maybeThrowRuntimeAndSuppress(ExceptionsHelper.java:199) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:331) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:357) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to read [id:205, legacy:false, file:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0/_state/node-205.st]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:325) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:357) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: [node_meta_data] unknown field [node_version], parser not found
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.getParser(ObjectParser.java:347) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.parse(ObjectParser.java:158) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.ObjectParser.apply(ObjectParser.java:182) ~[elasticsearch-x-content-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeMetaData$1.fromXContent(NodeMetaData.java:110) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeMetaData$1.fromXContent(NodeMetaData.java:94) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.read(MetaDataStateFormat.java:199) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.gateway.MetaDataStateFormat.loadLatestState(MetaDataStateFormat.java:320) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.loadOrCreateNodeMetaData(NodeEnvironment.java:357) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.env.NodeEnvironment.<init>(NodeEnvironment.java:245) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:270) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.node.Node.<init>(Node.java:252) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap$5.<init>(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.setup(Bootstrap.java:213) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Bootstrap.init(Bootstrap.java:326) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.Elasticsearch.init(Elasticsearch.java:136) ~[elasticsearch-6.3.2.jar:6.3.2]
        ... 6 more
```

Do someone have any idea for a quick fix ?

Comment: Also update Kibana?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I post my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the upgrade issue.
Downgraded seems to be forbidden so I had no choice to upgrade elasticsearch and kibana versions.